# The SQL Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to insert data from Northwind can anyone help me?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DimOrder]
    SELECT 
        [OrderID], [CustomerID], [OrderDate], [EmployeeID]
    FROM 
        Northwind..[Orders]
```

Comment: What columns does your `DimOrder` table have?? I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the columns you want to insert into - to avoid issues like this one (and others)

Comment: Add the createstatement of "DimOrder"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Like This:

```
Insert Into [dbo].[DimOrder] (ColumnName1,ColumnName2,..) select ColumnName1,ColumnName2,.. From Northwind.[Orders]
```

You Select Statement Should return same number of column, which your are inserting..

Answer (score 0):

to insert data using

```
insert into table#1
Select 
   filed#1,filed#2,filed#3
From table#2
```

you must consider following rules

1. if count of columns in table#1 must be equal with count of columns in select clause
2. data type of columns in table#1 must be equal with data type in order by column inselect claue